# Run Splash From File

Tags: web-crawler, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I've been researching this for a few days, I've found a lot of answers that are kind of like my question, but not really so I decided to go ahead and post this question. I'm using scrapy-splash to crawl KBB. I was able to get around the stupid first time use popup thing by using send_text and send_keys, this works super well in the browser version of Splash. It pulls in the dynamic content just like I want, AWESOME!

[image]

Here's the code for easy copy-paste-ability;

```
function main(splash, args)
  assert(splash:go(args.url))
  assert(splash:wait(0.5))
  splash:send_text("24153")
  splash:send_keys("<Return>")
  assert(splash:wait(5))
  return {
    html = splash:html(),
    png = splash:png(),
    har = splash:har(),
  }
end
```

Now I'm trying to make it work in-script because I want to be able to render multiple HTML files all at once. This is the code I have so far, I just have two URLs in there to test for now:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "cars"
    start_urls = ["https://www.kbb.com/ford/escape/2017/titanium/", "https://www.kbb.com/honda/cr-v/2017/touring/"]

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse,
                endpoint='render.html',
                args={'wait': 0.5, 'send_text':24153, 'send_keys':'<Return>', 'wait': 5.0},
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'car-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

When I try to run this it just keeps telling me that things timed out:

```
2018-01-16 19:34:31 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 1 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-01-16 19:35:02 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://192.168.65.0:8050/robots.txt> (failed 2 times): TCP connection timed out: 60: Operation timed out.
2018-01-16 19:35:31 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 1 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-01-16 19:36:17 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://192.168.65.0:8050/robots.txt> (failed 3 times): TCP connection timed out: 60: Operation timed out.
2018-01-16 19:36:17 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://192.168.65.0:8050/robots.txt>: TCP connection timed out: 60: Operation timed out.
twisted.internet.error.TCPTimedOutError: TCP connection timed out: 60: Operation timed out.
2018-01-16 19:36:31 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 1 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-01-16 19:37:31 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 1 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-01-16 19:37:32 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.kbb.com/ford/escape/2017/titanium/ via http://192.168.65.0:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): TCP connection timed out: 60: Operation timed out.
2018-01-16 19:37:32 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.kbb.com/honda/cr-v/2017/touring/ via http://192.168.65.0:8050/render.html> (failed 1 times): TCP connection timed out: 60: Operation timed out.
2018-01-16 19:38:31 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 1 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-01-16 19:38:48 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.kbb.com/ford/escape/2017/titanium/ via http://192.168.65.0:8050/render.html> (failed 2 times): TCP connection timed out: 60: Operation timed out.
2018-01-16 19:38:48 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.kbb.com/honda/cr-v/2017/touring/ via http://192.168.65.0:8050/render.html> (failed 2 times): TCP connection timed out: 60: Operation timed out.
```

This is my settings.py custom stuff at the bottom, not sure you need the whole thing since most of it is commented out:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}

SPLASH_URL = 'http://localhost:8050/'
SPLASH_URL = 'http://192.168.65.0:8050' 

SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}

DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'
```

I've been following multiple tutorials trying to get this to work. I'm assuming it has something to do with that SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES thing but I don't know what needs to change with that. I'm VERY new to spiders so any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: TL;DR: Try to remove SPLASH_URL = 'http://192.168.65.0:8050' from your config 

The key issue in your case is how you run Splash - because looks like Scrapy just can't reach it. I assume you run it in Docker, if so I'd recommend to  update your post with information about OS and Docker version you run.

Comment: I got rid of that line and now it actually runs which is nice. I am using Docker, version 17.12.0-ce-mac49 (21995). I have a MacBook running High Sierra. Unfortunately I realized that KBB did not have all the info that I needed for my task so I had to switch to AutoBlog. I still can't get it to run Lua scripts though. I'm now trying to get it to render the full page instead of just the top and cannot figure it out. I have been referencing this site: http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html but it isn't super helpful for newbies. Where do I put the lines when I'm using a code file?

Comment: Update, using mouse_click I got it to scroll and everything is great on that side again. Now I just need to run it in script like I was trying to do before.

Comment: Okay, I think I got it working except I don't know how to export the html that is rendered in the Lua script to a file since the parse function is no longer being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took almost two weeks but I FINALLY got what I wanted. Had to switch to AutoBlog because KBB didn't have everything I needed. Problem with AutoBlog is that it only loads the bottom of the page when you actually scroll to it, so I used mouse_click to click on a navigation button to scroll it down to the part of the page I needed. I then waited a few seconds before rendering.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "cars"
    start_urls = ["https://www.autoblog.com/buy/2017-Ford-Escape-SE__4dr_4x4/", "https://www.autoblog.com/buy/2017-Honda-CR_V-EX_L__4dr_Front_wheel_Drive/"]

    script="""
    function main(splash, args)
      assert(splash:go(args.url))
      assert(splash:wait(10.0))
      splash:mouse_click(800, 335)  
      assert(splash:wait(10.0))
      return {
        html = splash:html()
      }
    end
    """

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse,
                endpoint='execute',
                args={'lua_source': self.script, 'wait': 1.0},
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'car-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Still some touch ups to do and need to add more URLs, but it is a functioning block of code!